# WebForms/MVC hybrid - dynamically redirect /default.aspx to /home/index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, url-rewriting, webforms

I have a legacy WebForms app that I'm converting to MVC bit by bit. I need to be able to dynamically redirect requests for /default.aspx and send them to /home/index action under certain conditions. If possible I'd like to avoid using Response.Redirect, and am unsure if URL Rewriting is what I need

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Umbraco CMS solution provides a nice example of how to perform this switch between webforms and MVC. It adds a module into the Http pipeline that determines which rendering engine to use and either rewrites the path for web forms requests or invokes an instance of  `System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule` to handle MVC requests.

You can find the code in the [RewriteToUmbracoHandler](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0420f4d89d14#src/Umbraco.Web/UmbracoModule.cs) method.